# i cant visualize Decision Tree for my id3 classifier in weka . what should i do?

Tags: weka, decision-tree

i cant visualize  Decision Tree for my id3 classifier in weka .for mushroom.arff i have preprocessed  data by deleting attributes containing empty instances and after i have applied id3 classifier but unable to visulize tree.

[image: here you can see visualize tree option is not enabled]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Technobium.com](http://technobium.com/decision-trees-explained-using-weka/)

> For the moment, the platform does not allow the visualization of the
>   ID3 generated trees.

Answer (score -1):

try to save your model as buffer result. i trayed to visualize the saved result and it worked to me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HOTs.png)

Comment: OP wanted an Id3 tree visualized, not J48 as in your screenshot. This output is not supported, since [Id3](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.packages/simpleEducationalLearningSchemes/weka/classifiers/trees/Id3.html) does not implement the [Drawable](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/core/Drawable.html) interface like J48.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).